# Css в Internet Explorer отображается неправильно

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, css

В общем есть навигация. В Google Chrome все отображается так, как надо.
Однако в Internet Explorer навигация сдвигается на несколько пикселей.

Вот сама навигация:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="1.html">12345</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="2.html">1234</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="3.html">123</a></li>
            <li><a href="4.html">456</a></li>
            <li><a href="5.html">789</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Вот стиль:

```
ul#menu,
ul#menu li,
ul#menu ul {
width: 160px; 
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

ul#menu li {
float: left; 
display: block !important; 
display: inline; 
}

ul#menu a {
display: block !important;
display: inline; 
background-color: #3d3e40;
padding-top:4px;
margin:0;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
height: auto !important;
}

ul#menu a:hover,
ul#menu li:hover a,
ul#menu li.iehover a {
text-decoration: none;
background: #648B43;
}

ul#menu li:hover li a,
ul#menu li.iehover li a {
background-color: #3d3e40;
}

ul#menu li:hover li a:hover,
ul#menu li:hover li:hover a,
ul#menu li.iehover li a:hover,
ul#menu li.iehover li.iehover a {
background: #648B43;
color: #FFF;
}

ul#menu li:hover li:hover li a,
ul#menu li.iehover li.iehover li a {
background: #648B43;
background-color: #3d3e40;
}

ul#menu li:hover li:hover li a:hover,
ul#menu li:hover li:hover li:hover a,
ul#menu li.iehover li.iehover li a:hover,
ul#menu li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover a {
background: #648B43;
color: #FFF;
}

ul#menu li:hover li:hover li:hover li a,
ul#menu li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover li a {
background: #648B43;
color: #BCD6A7;
}

ul#menu li:hover li:hover li:hover li a:hover,
ul#menu li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover li a:hover {
background: #648B43;
color: #FFF;
}

ul#menu ul,
ul#menu ul ul,
ul#menu ul ul ul {
margin-left: 160px;
margin-top: -24px;
position:absolute;
}

ul#menu li:hover ul ul,
ul#menu li:hover ul ul ul,
ul#menu li.iehover ul ul,
ul#menu li.iehover ul ul ul {
display: none;
}

ul#menu li:hover ul,
ul#menu ul li:hover ul,
ul#menu ul ul li:hover ul,
ul#menu li.iehover ul,
ul#menu ul li.iehover ul,
ul#menu ul ul li.iehover ul {
display: block;
}
```

Не знаю как решить. Можно вот здесь - поменять в ul#menu a { padding-top:4px;} - можно поменять тут - например поставить 3 px. Тогда в internet Explorer все будет гуд. Однако теперь в Google chrome все сдвинется на пиксель.
Спасибо!

Comment: Это у Вас в ИЕ10 уежает?

Comment: ДА. именно там

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так

```
<script> if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { 
var headHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML; 
    headHTML    += '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie10.css">'; 
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = headHTML; 
} 
</script>
```

Это всвязи с тем, что ИЕ10 условные комментарии неподдерживает.
Создаем файл ie10.css и прописываем стили.

Comment: в head вставляется этот скрипт
в ie10.css прописываешь ul#menu a { padding-top:3px;}

Comment: все сделал как ты написал - ничего не поменялось. как будто не происходит перенаправления на ie10.css

Comment: в какой папке находиться ie10.css - должны находиться в папке css.
Если у Вас папка имеет свое название - измените в скрипте css/ - на свое название папки

Comment: бросил прям в корень.
путь href="ie10.css"

Comment: не работает? ссылку киньте где это меню! ЗНАЧИТ У ВАС ИЕ9, ПОЭТОМУ и НЕРАБОТАЛО

ИЕ10 УСЛОВНЫЕ КОММЕНТАРИИ НЕ ПОДДЕРЖИВАЕТ!!!!!!!!!

Comment: нет. ничего не изменилось. как будто не видит этот файл.

Comment: Изменил на вот это - чтобы все IE поддерживало.

<!--[if IE]> 

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ie10.css" />
  
<![endif]-->